# Redirect URL using NGINX Proxy

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon AWS S3 bucket setup, with access to the files using an url. For esthetic purposes, I'd like to access these files using a cleaner URL, rather than the amazon provided one. Something like this:

```
https://amazon-aws-url.com/bucket-name/filename.png -> https://subdomain.domain.com/filename.png
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to configure my NGINX server to proxy these requests?

Any help is much appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the bucket 'www.exampledomain.com' and have web hosting enabled, then update the CNAME for 'www.exampledomain.com' to point to the bucket hosting URL, that will take you to the bucket location when you use your custom domain.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

If you would like a HTTPS serverless implementation, I would recommend using a CloudFront Distribution in front of your S3 bucket.

https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/setup-aws-s3-static-website-hosting-using-ssl-acm-34d41d32e394

Both of these solutions are far more cost-effective than setting up a server. However, if you would definitely like to setup an NGINX proxy server, then an instructional article is below.

https://medium.com/happy-cog/deploying-static-websites-to-aws-s3-behind-an-nginx-proxy-fd51cc0c53ec